# Webpack/ Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

after installing babel-polyfill and  babel-preset-es2015 I have an error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.

here is devDependencies in `package.json`

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.5",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.7.0"
  }
```

and `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "es2015", "stage-0" ],
  "plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is related to some old babel stuff being found in your project.

In your case in your presets you have the "@babel/preset-env" and "@babel/preset-react" updated to the latest, but the es2015 and stage-0 are older dependencies and also need to be updated and replaced.

So in the case of es2015 since you are running @babel/preset-env I don't actually think you need to run es2015 or stage-0, but as long as you have them in your presets you will be getting the error.

Also you should consider providing the full error, for example in my case it was something like

```
ERROR in ./demo2.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at /Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at /Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:58:104
    at cachedFunction (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:62:27)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/gensync/index.js:244:28)
    at sync (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/Tiling/demo/node_modules/gensync/index.js:84:14)
```

So you can see how that extra information there might help someone trying to look at your question realize where the problem is at.